# jQuery selector with length

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is simplified version of HTML:

```
            <ul class="list">
                <li>
                    <ul class="list">
                        <li>
                            <ul class="list">
                                <li></li>
                                <li></li>
                                <li></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <ul class="list">
                                <li></li>
                                <li></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <ul class="list">
                                <li></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
```

I need to select every UL.list that has less than 3 items and give it class "few-items".
This code is simplifed. Originally list is huge with several levels.

Thank you very much in advance :)

Comment: Tried anything yet? And by "less than 3 items" do you mean three children, or three descendant elements?

Answer (score 2):

Using [filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) would be the best solution :

```
$('.list').filter(function(){
   return $(this).children().length<3
}).addClass('few-items');
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can do that:

```
$('ul').filter(function() { 
    return $(this).children('li').length < 3; 
}).addClass( 'few-items' );
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("ul").each(function(index) {
  if($(this).children("li").length < 3)
  {
    $(this).addClass("few-items")
  }
});
```